# did i do anything wrong with webview_flutter when i want to run some javascript in onPageStarted method

Tags: flutter, webview-flutter

```
onPageStarted: (url) async {
                  var controller = await _controller.future;
                  await controller.runJavascript(_historyJavascriptCode);
                  if (javascriptCodeOnStart != null) {
                    for (String jscode in javascriptCodeOnStart!) {
                      await controller.runJavascript(jscode);
                    }
                  }
                },
```

this only effects when the app is first opened, when i open it again, it fails. it just happens on ios newer than 15.0

webview_flutter: ^3.0.4
ios 15.5

Comment: its ok after i put them into the onPageFinished method, maybe onPageStarted needs some fix